# Yellow spots appeared in my lawn suddenly although all other area is green

Tags: diagnosis, lawn, grass, lawn-repair, sod

I live in southeast Michigan. I built my house 2 years ago and had sod laid down last year.

I was told to water twice a day at least. The grass has held in and it came green during this season with no issues. I have reduced the watering to a single time a day and everything was perfect.

Suddenly within 2 days yellow spots appeared in different areas of the lawn.

I used Grub control in May of this year.
I used Scott turf builder weed and feed in June.
I applied grass food in July.

What is causing these yellow spots? How do I fix them?

Update: here are some pictures from different areas.
[image]

[image]

this is close to the garage [image]

and here is another picture in my back yard all by it self [image]

this one is next to the side walk(and could be dog pee) [image]

Comment: Please post a photograph of the affected areas. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and thank you for the question. Are you able to post a photo of the lawn showing the spots themselves as well as their location within the landscape? This will be of great value in helping people to identify the issue.

Comment: Interesting...were you there when they laid the sod?  Do you know how they prepared the lawn bed?  And please, hear what I say, do NOT ever apply chemicals that you do not understand!  Especially grub control!!  That actually sets you up for huge infestations the next year that will kill grass.  You kill all the beneficials that CONTROL populations of grubs.  Once one kills EVERYTHING in the soil, you are so (is it ok to say) screwed!!  Find out if they rolled the lawn bed before laying the sod.   Please send more pictures...and tell us you maintenance practice/watering.

Comment: And you  NEVER water every day...read some of the other threads on lawn care, watering, fertilizing that are on this site.  They are precious.

Comment: Dog urine is a common cause.

Comment: Does a single application of dog urine cause yellowing?  Or does it need to be frequent?

Comment: One pee pee (usually a female) will totally yellow whatever grass is assaulted with the pee if the lawn is lush and green (properly fertilized).  Now if that lawn is not well fertilized, those pee peed spots on the lawn will be the greenish spots on a stressed, deficient lawn.  Dark green. Great point Ecnerwal!!!

Comment: ٍSorry for the delay in response to all. I will try to post some pictures today when I get back home.

Comment: @stormy : yes i was there when they laid the sod. the lot was cleaned and about 2 inch topsoil was spread before they laid the sod.

Comment: @GrahamChiu and others referring to dog Urine; I wold understand that it is that if the yellow spots are in the front lawn only and close to the sidewalk. but they are in different areas and different sizes (from 2 sq ft to 10 sq ft)

Comment: Now you've got us so curious you just HAVE to post a picture of these spots.  I think the urine thing is the best and most likely without the benefit of pictures.  I've one other possibility but I'll wait for your pictures!!

Comment: Muthanna, do you remember them grading, raking, rolling that soil?  If one doesn't roll the lawn bed one will have all kinds of depressions, high spots perhaps not that visible to the eye but there will be a disconnect of the sod to the soil.  This is the other reason for yellow spots.  But I am thinking dog pee.  Easy peasy to fix.  Need to put a sign on your lawn to tell your neighbors to not allow their doggies to pee on your lawn!  Otherwise, flooding the spot of pee will help tremendously...if you see the dog in action.  Send pictures, many other solutions!

Comment: @stormy as far as the prep work for the lot, I don't remember them rolling the lawn bed. I posted some pics may be that helps.

Comment: Is there any possibility there is buried debris of some sort below those patches - rocks, bricks, piles of sand or cement, that kind of  thing?

Comment: get a spade and dig a six inch deep test hole in one of the dead areas.  Whatever it is the cause is underground!

Comment: Looks like grub damage I'd check for grubs even though you treated for them. Also, fungus can hit like that, especially if its dry out, or if you have nitrogen burn.

Comment: @J.Musser ;I was told by some friends and family members that it could be grubs. I will treat and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I walk in my suburban neighborhood.  Most laws are very green except for an expanse that is near the sidewalk, which has yellow patches of various diameters.  This is where dogs are walked daily.

I agree, it only takes one pee and the yellow appears.  I like dogs and cats, so I don't mind.

Comment: One of the small spots is near the side walk but the others are not.